# Reloading iframes with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, iframe, reload

I have a webpage, **A.html**, that has several links and an iframe with a page, **B.html**, that loads into **A**'s iframe when **A.html** loads.  When **A.html** loads, I have a simple bit of javascript that determines the height of the document to be loaded into the iframe when **A** loads and sizes the iframe accordingly so that I do not have to use scrollbars.

When I click on one of the links in **A.html**, I want **B.html** to be replaced with whatever page the link in **A** takes me to (we'll call this one **C.html**).  Now, when **C** loads into **A**'s iframe, **C.html** will have a link to yet another page that opens up in **A**'s iframe, which I will **D.html**.

Now, I can make **B**, **C**, and **D** show up in **A**'s iframe in the manner I would like.  What I'm trying to figure out how to do is to apply that bit of JavaScript that figures out the height of **B.html** when **A** loads and apply it to **C** and **D** and so forth so that the iframe is always just  tall enough to show the entire document without having white space.

At this point, I'm in over my head and figure I will need to figure out how to rewrite the script and probably a big chunk of the page as well.  Said code is available upon request, as is anything else needed to clarify any points I've made.

Comment: at first, for your information: iframe is a depreciated tag for a long time. better use the object tag instead. If the source that you load into the iframes is yours, try to use ajax. No problems with heights and other iframe related things.

Comment: @Erwinus: `IFRAME` tag is not deprecated nor obsolete. It exists since HTML4.01 and still is in HTML5 standards.

Comment: @jay: Ah, I see that you are right. But remember that HTML5 is still not an official standard.

Comment: How would I go about this in an object tag?  I apologize, I'm largely self-teaching as I go and I'm doing this out of personal interest.

Answer (score 0):

You might try using page A's iframe onload event.

```
iframeOnPageA.onload = function() {
    //insert resizing code here
};
```

Every time the iframe loads, the function should get called.

Comment: <*iframe id="IFrame" name="IFrame" onload = "setIframeHeight( this.id )" src="iframe.html" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" width="100%"></iframe*> This is my iframe code on page A.  How might I implement your solution, exactly?  I do apologize, I'm largely teaching myself as I go.  I'm very grateful for your help.